# How to enable and attach clickHandler event on a link in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I want to enable a link inside a column which in turn a part of grid.

this is how code looks

```
private ColumnModel<XYZ> getmodel(String screen){
    List<ColumnConfig<XYZ, ? >> columnList = new ArrayList<>();
    columnList.add(date);
    .
    .
    .
    columnList.add(linkCol);
    linkCol.setCell(new AbstractCell<String>() {
        @Override
        public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            final int index = context.getIndex();
            XYZ audit = store.get(index);
            if(audit!=null) {
                Anchor hyperLink = new Anchor("Link l1");
                hyperLink.addStyleName("hyperLinkCursor");
                sb.appendHtmlConstant(hyperLink.toString());
                
                hyperLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                    @Override
                    Public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        LOG,Fine("clicked on link1");
                    }
                });
                
            }
        }
    });
    return new ColumnModel<>(colunList);
}
```

please help, and if any more info required please let me know.
i have been stuck on this thing since long

initially had click handler on cell, tried removing that.
the flow is not even going inside the handler method....dont know if this is the correct way to invoke a hyperlink or not.

cant use click handler on the cell level, as there are going to be multiple links in the same column, and want to perform different actions on each different link clicks.

Comment: Do you need to have multiple links in one cell? If so, is the number of links the same in each cell?

Comment: yes in the same cell, links are going to be same throughout...its just that based on some condition need to disable enable links

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it solves your problem, but try this

To handle clicks in `DatGrid` cell use

```
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.createCustomManager(
      new DefaultSelectionEventManager.EventTranslator<YourTableType>() {

       @Override
       public DefaultSelectionEventManager.SelectAction translateSelectionEvent(CellPreviewEvent<OrderListEntryWAccessInfo> event) {
           NativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
           if (BrowserEvents.CLICK.equals(nativeEvent.getType())) {
               if (event.getColumn() == table.getColumnIndex(columnName)) { 
                    // here you can extract value from cell
                    Window.open(event.getValue())
                    return DefaultSelectionEventManager.SelectAction.IGNORE;
                     }
                 return DefaultSelectionEventManager.SelectAction.IGNORE;
                }
                return DefaultSelectionEventManager.SelectAction.DEFAULT;
             }
       }));
```